# java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: java, pointers, arraylist, null

I have this problem with my code. Its called java.lang.nullpointerexception. and I cant seem to fix it. please help me take a look at it. Thank you. I didnt include the class name and import. class name is called CHORD. I didnt make public static since my assginemnt say dont use global variable.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> nodeList;

public static void main(String[] args){


    CHORD obj = new CHORD();
    obj.nodeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    String filename ="";

    if(args.length ==1){
    filename = args[0];
    obj.read(filename);
    }

}

public void read(String file){
    CHORD obj = new CHORD();
    obj = null;

    Scanner loadFile = null;
    try{
    loadFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
    String inputLine;

    while(loadFile.hasNextLine()){
        inputLine = loadFile.nextLine();

        String[] inputArray = inputLine.split(" ",3);

        if(inputArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("init")){

            int size = Integer.parseInt(inputArray[1]);
            setSizeFT(init(size));  
        }
        else if(inputArray[0].equalsIgnoreCase("addpeer")){
            System.out.println("adding");
            nodeList.add(Integer.parseInt(inputArray[1]));

        }
    }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException x){

    }
    finally{
        System.out.println(getFT());
        loadFile.close();
    }
    System.out.println(getFT());
}

public void print(){
    CHORD obj = new CHORD();
    for(int x =0; x< obj.nodeList.size(); x++){
        System.out.println(obj.nodeList.get(x));
    }
}


public int init(int num){
    int n = 23;
    double k = Math.ceil(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2));
    int size = (int)k;
    return size;
}

public void setSizeFT(int size){
    sizeFT = size;
}

public int getFT(){
    return sizeFT;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the CHORD class? And don't name your class with ALLCAPS letters.

Comment: `nodeList` is probably `null` - check with `if (obj.nodeList == null)`

Comment: Please can you tell us at which line appear the exception? and try also to post Chord class code too

Comment: @RohitJain    I just edited my post..please check

Answer (score 4):

Here's an explanation of what NullPointerException's are: http://antwerkz.com/dealing-with-nullpointerexceptions/  From the article:

> The most common (and obvious to the seasoned developer) is that you didn't initialize a variable.

Looking at that line, it looks like `obj.nodeList` may be null.  Here's how I deduced that:

1. I can see that `obj` is not null, because the first line is `CHORD obj = new CHORD();`.  That means you didn't set `obj` to null.
2. I can tell that `Integer` is not null.  That's a class and you're calling a static method.  That can't be null because there's nothing to be assigned there.
3. `inputArray[1]` *may* return null, but if that were happening, your stack trace would not end on this line, it would probably end on some line inside `Integer.parseInt`.  I'd need to see a full stack trace to be sure though.  But looking at the [javadoc of Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29), it doesn't say it'll throw a NPE so that's even more evidence to rule it out.
4. If `inputArray` was null, you'd probably get the error on the first if statement so I can rule that out.

Somewhere your code needs to do a `obj.nodeList = new NodeList()` or something like that.  I can't say for sure without seeing what the CHORD class looks like.

Comment: here is what my code looks like..I kinda get what you mean and i declear obj.nodeList = new ArrayList<Int>()l above there also.

Comment: @KevinPotatoo Can you show us the code where you do that?  Also, can you show us your error message?  Copy and paste it into your question exactly how it prints out.  It'll help us answer.

Comment: i can not post the code here due to too many words..I am pretty new to this website..:(

Comment: is there anyway i can show u the code?

Comment: @ tieTYT i cant show you the code cos the website say too many words..

Comment: Yes, show it in your original question by editing it, not as a comment.

Comment: yea..done.I just edit my original post..

Comment: That's not everything I wanted to see, but one thing you're doing is saying new Chord() everywhere.  Each time you do that you create a new one with a null nodeList (I can only assume).  So the nodeList you set somewhere is not the same chord as the other ones.

Comment: oh ..i got it already..its because i use obj.nodeList ..cause u say "I can see that obj is not null, because the first line is CHORD obj = new CHORD();. That means you didn't set obj to null."